# Changing zoom in kids outlines in PDF files

Tags: c#, pdf, recursion, itext

I would like to change zoom in bookmarks (outlines) in PDF files. I have done it for parent bookmarks but I don't know how to do it for `kids`. I can read 'Kids' but I'm having difficulties implementing recursion to change zoom for non-parent bookmarks. I would really appreciate suggestions as to how to approach the problem.
My code (working OK):

```
var bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
var newBookmarks = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

for (int i = 0; i < bookmarks.Count; i++)
{
    string zoomValue = "1.25";

    if (bookmarks[i]["Title"].ToString() == "Cover" ||
        bookmarks[i]["Title"].ToString() == "C")
    {
        zoomValue = "1";
    }

    int pageNumber = Int32.Parse(bookmarks[i]["Page"]
        .ToString().Split(' ')[0]);
    // increase pageHight by one to have a nicer zoom
    float pageHeight = reader.GetPageSize(pageNumber).Height + 1;
    string replaceValue = $"{pageNumber} XYZ 0 {pageHeight} {zoomValue}";
    newBookmarks.AddRange(ChangeZoom(bookmarks, i, replaceValue));

}

private static IList<Dictionary<string, object>>
    ChangeZoom(IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks, int i, string replaceValue)
{
    bookmarks[i]["Page"] = replaceValue;
    if (bookmarks[i].ContainsKey("Kids"))
    {
        var kids = (List<Dictionary<string, object>>)bookmarks[i]["Kids"];
        // recursion here?
    }
    return bookmarks;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with iText framework, but if you just need to set replaceValue to all child bookmarks you can do it such way:

```
public void Meth(PdfReader reader)
{
    foreach (var prntBookmark in SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader))
    {
        ChangeZoom(prntBookmark, reader);           
    }
}
private static void ChangeZoom(Dictionary<string, object> bookmark, PdfReader reader)
{
    string zoomValue = "1.25";

    if (bookmark["Title"].ToString() == "Cover" ||
    bookmark["Title"].ToString() == "C")
    {
        zoomValue = "1";
    }

    int pageNumber = Int32.Parse(bookmark["Page"].ToString().Split(' ')[0]);
    // increase pageHight by one to have a nicer zoom
    float pageHeight = reader.GetPageSize(pageNumber).Height + 1;
    bookmark["Page"] = $"{pageNumber} XYZ 0 {pageHeight} {zoomValue}";

    if (bookmark.ContainsKey("Kids"))
    {
        (bookmark["Kids"] as List<Dictionary<string, object>>)?.ForEach(bm=>ChangeZoom(bm, reader));
    }
}
```

..

```
(bookmark["Kids"] as List<Dictionary<string, object>>)?.ForEach(bm=>ChangeZoom(bm, reader));
```

Is the same as

```
var kidBookmarks =(bookmark["Kids"] as List<Dictionary<string, object>>);
foreach (var bm in kidBookmarks)
        {
            ChangeZoom(bm, reader);         
        }
```

Such a way you iterate through all child bookmarks recursive and change a zoom.

Comment: Thanks for this. You are close as your code changes bookmarks but all child bookmarks point to their parent. I have found releveant code [here at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30182651/2657875), however, I don't know how to rewrite it. Perhaps you know it?

Comment: I have edited the code.. Your link is about merging, your question is about changing the zoom.

Comment: Unfortuently, the code won't compile. In in the method `ChangeZoom` there is object `reader` as it should be given as parameter to be visible for the method. The link is about merging, but the code is very similiar as it changes bookmarks and creates new one.

Comment: It is of `PdfReader` type. It would be also better to create new bookmarks as in the other code -- the one I link to.

Comment: I have edited one more time, sorry, I have not Visual Studio at this moment, can not check it.

Comment: In your code you work with bookmarks variable, it is of reference type, therefore also in your code you change the original bookmarks. So if you want, to change copy of your bookmarks, then make deep copy from your (SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader)) object and make iteration through the copy.

Comment: Does my code change the zoom of kids bookmarks in the same manner like your code change the zoom of parent bookmark?

Comment: Yes, it seems it does since each bookmarks is now of zoom 125%. Thanks for your help. Could you explain in your answer what `(bookmark["Kids"] as List<Dictionary<string, object>>)?.ForEach(bm=>ChangeZoom(bm, reader));` does? I will mark your answer as such.

Comment: Thanks for this. One more question: what does this line mean? `(bookmark["Kids"] as List<Dictionary<string, object>>)`

Comment: bookmark is of type Dictionary<string, object>, so bookmark["Kids"] is of type object, so you need to cast it to the right type: (List<Dictionary<string, object>>)(bookmark["Kids"]) or (bookmark["Kids"] as List<Dictionary<string, object>>)